# Simple question about slicing a Numpy Tensor

Tags: numpy, slice

I have a Numpy Tensor,

```
X = np.arange(64).reshape((4,4,4))
```

I wish to grab the 2,3,4 entries of the first dimension of this tensor, which you can do with,

```
Y = X[[1,2,3],:,:]
```

Is this a simpler way of writing this instead of explicitly writing out the indices [1,2,3]? I tried something like [1,:], which gave me an error.

Context: for my real application, the shape of the tensor is something like (30000,100,100). I would like to grab the last (10000, 100,100) to (30000,100,100) of this tensor.

Comment: There is no need for the `:` in the last dimensions. Just `X[[1,2,3]]` is enough. And since the indexes are continuous, you can also do `X[1:4]`.

Comment: While @darcamo is correct you don't need to add the extra `:` in the slice, it's nice for readability's sake to be able to discern that it's a rank-3 slice: `X[1:4,:,:]`

Comment: What's the error with `[1,:]`?

Comment: @hpaulj Y = X[[1,:],:,:]
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It's either `x[1,:]` or `x[1:,:]`.  `numpy` extends basic python list indexing. `alist[1]` and `alist[1:]` are valid.  A syntax error is produced by the python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way in your case is to use `X[1:4]`. This is the same as `X[[1,2,3]]`, but notice that with `X[1:4]` you only need one pair of brackets because `1:4` already represent a range of values.

For an `N` dimensional array in NumPy if you specify indexes for less than `N` dimensions you get all elements of the remaining dimensions. That is, for `N` equal to 3, `X[1:4]` is the same as `X[1:4, :, :]` or `X[1:4, :]`. Only if you want to index some dimension while getting all elements in a dimension that comes before it is that you actually need to pass `:`. Such as `X[:, 2:4]`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to select from some row to the end of array, simply use python slicing notation as below:

```
X[10000:,:,:]
```

This will select all rows from 10000 to the end of array and all columns and depths for them.